# How to exclude strings with preceding symbol?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two simple strings:

```
s = "7/20-21 Hello, World."
s2 = "20-21 Hello, World."
```

What would be correct regex pattern that would only find the numbers in the second string?
I'm trying to extract "20-21" only if there are no preceding symbols...
Both versions below still gets me "20-21" from the first string:

```
"[^/]?[0-9]{1,2}[/|-][0-9]{1,2}[\s]{1}"
"[^/][0-9]{1,2}[/|-][0-9]{1,2}[\s]{1}"
```

This version gives me an error...

```
"(?<![/])[0-9]{1,2}[/|-][0-9]{1,2}[\s]{1}"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [`^[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}\s`](https://regex101.com/r/MTW4qy/1/)?

Comment: Or, [`(?<!\S)[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}\s`](https://regex101.com/r/MTW4qy/2) / [`(?:\s|^)[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}\s`](https://regex101.com/r/MTW4qy/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew third example worked! If you will post it as an answer I will mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\s|^)[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MTW4qy/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\s|^)` - either a whitespace (`\s`) or (`|`) a start of a string
- `[0-9]{1,2}` -  1 or 2 digits
- `[/-]` - a `/` or `-`
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\s` - a single whitespace

Answer (score 0):

If you can use anchors:

```js
const s = '7/20-21 Hello, World.';
const s2 = '20-21 Hello, World.';

const regexAnchor = /^(\d{1,2}[/|-]\d{1,2})/;

console.log([
  {
    value: s,
    match: s.match(regexAnchor)
  },
  
  {
    value: s2,
    match: s2.match(regexAnchor)
  }
]);
```